# MassTransit suggestion to provide a container agnostic Scope Provider with IServiceProvider as a payload

Tags: masstransit

I am asking this question here before submitting an issue on the MassTransit repo...

Currently, there are many MassTransit container extensions that provide implementations of scope providers that add a container specific interface to the payload of `ConsumeContext`.

For example:

- `AutofacConsumerScopeProvider`

  - Payload type: `Autofac.ILifetimeScope`
- `DependencyInjectionConsumerScopeProvider`

  - Payload type: `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScope`
- `StructureMapConsumerScopeProvider`

  - Payload type: `StructureMap.IContainer`
- etc...

Instead wouldn't it be better if all these extensions add `IServiceProvider` to the context payload versus their container specific interface so that downstream consumers may decouple themselves from the container framework?

Right now, we have to use the following logic to get access to the underlying `IServiceProvider`:

```cs
interface IWidgetService
{
    Task DoSomethingAsync();
}

class WidgetService : IWidgetService
{
    public Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IWidgetService, WidgetService>();

    services.AddTransient<IConsumerScopeProvider, DependencyInjectionConsumerScopeProvider>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IConsumerFactory<>), typeof(ScopeConsumerFactory<>));
}

private static IBusControl CreateBus(IServiceProvider serviceProviderRoot)
{
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(bus =>
    {
        var host = bus.Host("127.0.0.1", "/", configurator =>
        {
            configurator.Username("guest");
            configurator.Password("guest");
        });

        bus.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test-queue", configurator =>
        {
            configurator.UseExecuteAsync(async context =>
            {
                var consumerScopeProvider = serviceProviderRoot.GetRequiredService<IConsumerScopeProvider>();
                using (var scope = consumerScopeProvider.GetScope(context))
                {
                    // this next line of code is where we must access the payload
                    // using a container specific interface to get access to the
                    // scoped IServiceProvider
                    var serviceScope = scope.Context.GetPayload<IServiceScope>();
                    var serviceProviderScoped = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

                    var widgetService = serviceProviderScoped.GetRequiredService<IWidgetService>();

                    await widgetService.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            });

            // additional receive endpoint configuration...
        });
    });

    return busControl;
}
```

Also, I am not sure if this is a bug, but won't the current implementation of `DependencyInjectionStateMachineActivityFactory` always throw an exception because nothing currently adds `IServiceProvider` to the payload context?

```cs
public class DependencyInjectionStateMachineActivityFactory :
    IStateMachineActivityFactory
{
    public Activity<TInstance, TData> GetActivity<TActivity, TInstance, TData>(BehaviorContext<TInstance, TData> context)
        where TActivity : Activity<TInstance, TData>
    {
        // this next line will always fail, correct?
        var serviceProvider = context.GetPayload<IServiceProvider>();

        return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TActivity>();
    }

    public Activity<TInstance> GetActivity<TActivity, TInstance>(BehaviorContext<TInstance> context) where TActivity : Activity<TInstance>
    {
        // this next line will always fail, correct?
        var serviceProvider = context.GetPayload<IServiceProvider>();

        return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TActivity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a bug I've just fixed.

Comment: And honestly, why aren't you just creating a consumer and taking your required service as a dependency on the constructor?

Comment: The reason is because I am trying to implement a middleware component (i.e. a filter to the consume pipeline) that adds custom logging functionality and I would prefer that it resolves its dependencies from the DI container using a per-request (i.e. scoped) lifetime. The changes you recently added are perfect and now allow me to do exactly that. Sorry, I probably should have shown that specific example in StackOverflow instead.

Comment: Great, that's why I added them :)

Comment: Hello! Is that resolved somehow? Can you provide a snippet for that? I'm trying to inject to a MT handler scoped service ``TenantReslover`` which would read ``TenantId`` value from header. The problem is, I don't understand how to get access ``ConsumeContext`` from ``TenantResolver``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few missing extension methods for the Microsoft Extensions Dependency Injection package, which I've added and were released with 5.0.2.